# how to search near by doctors addresses which are stored in my database on google map?

Tags: android

I am developing one application which displays 
current location of user also displays doctors 
on near by him on google map.I developed one 
demo application which can find any location 
and put a marker on it but I don't know how to 
find near by addresses which are stored in database.

```
 **My XML File:**

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
       android:layout_height="fill_parent">
     <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <EditText 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:id="@+id/location"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:text="White House" />
            <Button 
                android:id="@+id/geocodeBtn" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:text="Find Location" />
       </LinearLayout>
       <com.google.android.maps.MapView
                     android:id="@+id/mapview"
                     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                     android:layout_height="320px"
                     android:clickable="true"
        android:apiKey=Z1oyeAgSpj5vGQVD6ADrUI2622o7yfJVJ3vEOA"

                     />

    </RelativeLayout>   

    **Manifest File:**

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="pkg.Map"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />


    <application 
        android:icon="@drawable/icon" 
        android:label="@string/app_name">
    <uses-library 
        android:name="com.google.android.maps">
    </uses-library>
        <activity 
            android:name="pkg.GeoCoderWithMarkers.GeoCoder"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action 
            android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category 
                android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


    </application>
    <uses-permission 
        android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission  
        android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission  
        android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
</manifest>
```

**and Java File:**

```
package pkg.GeoCoderWithMarkers;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import pkg.Map.R;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.ItemizedOverlay;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapController;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.maps.MyLocationOverlay;
import com.google.android.maps.OverlayItem;

 public class GeoCoder extends MapActivity {
    private MapController mapController;
    private MapView mapView;
    GeoPoint p,p1;
    private MyLocationOverlay me=null;
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private Geocoder geocoder = null;
     int lat;
     int lng;

    //** Called when the activity is first created. *//*
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        mapView = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

        GeoPoint pt = new GeoPoint((int)(5.34079*1000000),
                (int)(100.28241*1000000));
        mapView.getController().setZoom(10);
        mapView.setStreetView(true);
        mapView.getController().setCenter(pt);
        Button geoBtn =(Button)findViewById(R.id.geocodeBtn);
        geocoder = new Geocoder(this);
        final Drawable marker=getResources().getDrawable
            (R.drawable.pushpin_blue);
        int markerWidth = marker.getIntrinsicWidth();
        int markerHeight = marker.getIntrinsicHeight();
        marker.setBounds(0, markerHeight, markerWidth, 0);



        MyItemizedOverlay myItemizedOverlay = 
                new MyItemizedOverlay(marker);
        mapView.getOverlays().add(myItemizedOverlay);

        GeoPoint myPoint1 = new GeoPoint(lat, 
                (int)(100.28241*1000000));
        myItemizedOverlay.addItem(myPoint1, 
            "myPoint1", "myPoint1");
        GeoPoint myPoint2 = new GeoPoint
            (50*1000000, 50*1000000);
        myItemizedOverlay.addItem
            (myPoint2, "myPoint2", "myPoint2");


        geoBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
             @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
          try {
            EditText loc = 
                (EditText)findViewById(R.id.location);

            String locationName = loc.getText().toString();
            List<Address> addressList = 
                geocoder.getFromLocationName
                (locationName, 5);
            if(addressList!=null && addressList.size()>0)
            {
              int lat = (int)(addressList.get(0).
                getLatitude()*1000000);
              int lng = (int)(addressList.get(0).
                getLongitude()*1000000);
              GeoPoint pt = new GeoPoint(lat,lng);
              mapView.getController().setZoom(17);
              mapView.getController().setCenter(pt);

              MyItemizedOverlay myItemizedOverlay = 
                new MyItemizedOverlay(marker);
              mapView.getOverlays().add(myItemizedOverlay);

              GeoPoint myPoint1 = new GeoPoint(lat, lng);
              myItemizedOverlay.addItem
                (myPoint1, "myPoint1", "myPoint1");
             // GeoPoint myPoint2 = new GeoPoint
                (50*1000000, 50*1000000);
             // myItemizedOverlay.addItem
                (myPoint2, "myPoint2", "myPoint2");
            }
          } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
        }});



    }
    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    return false;
    }


 }
 class MyItemizedOverlay extends 
        ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem>{

    private ArrayList<OverlayItem> 
        overlayItemList = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();

    public MyItemizedOverlay(Drawable marker) {
    super(boundCenterBottom(marker));
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

    populate();
    }



    public void addItem(GeoPoint p, 
            String title, String snippet){
    OverlayItem newItem = 
        new OverlayItem(p, title, snippet);
    overlayItemList.add(newItem);
       populate();
    }

    @Override
    protected OverlayItem createItem(int i) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return overlayItemList.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return overlayItemList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas, 
            MapView mapView, boolean shadow) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);
    //boundCenterBottom(marker);
    }

 }
```

Comment: Does you database contains fields like latitude & longitude ? If so you can get the current latitude & longitude and based on this location search the lowest distance's latitude & longitude. You can find ready made , distance calculation between two lat-lon. Based on the Distance you can search near by Doctor

Answer (score 1):

The `Location`-Class offers you a pretty nice Method: `distanceTo(GeoPoint)`.
So just iterate through your doctor's GeoPoints with this Method.

Answer (score 0):

you can define the specific radius and calculate the distance from your location to doctors addresses and find the distance and as per radius set and check whether it's in radius or not then show the near by doctor addresses.

For this you need to check every time when the location was change into the service so you can found the near by locations.

Comment: can u provide me a small example?